# Strange error on JWT Laravel when using Multi Tenant Application

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm using this package for "jwt-auth" for my Laravel backend project, here is the link for the package:

https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

I have 2 middleware that I put the names Tenant and JWT, when my user tries to log in to the app he must send the company code, so my middleware Tenant picks the information from the specific connection database client and all is working fine.

But when I use 2 middlewares together, he gives me an error that I don't have a user table. He is right because when I made a searching from the problem I found that the package executes a function before all my 2 middlewares that is this:

```
  /**
     * Get the currently authenticated user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function user()
    {
        // MODIFICAÇÃO CUSTOMIZADA DA FUNÇÃO USER
        if ($this->user !== null) {
            return $this->user;
        }
        if ($this->jwt->setRequest($this->request)->getToken() &&
            ($payload = $this->jwt->check(true)) &&
            $this->validateSubject()
        ) {
            return $this->user = $this->provider->retrieveById($payload['sub']);
        }
    }
```

The problem was solved if I comment this line **"return $this->user = $this->provider->retrieveById($payload['sub']);"**, but this is not a good practice. The main reason for this error is that this function is executed before my Tenant middleware that doesn't have a user table in the database that Tenant middleware tries to connect.

The file name is **JWT_GUARD.php in tymon\jwt-auth\src**, i'm think is something about my configuration that i must change in

config/auth.php from laravel

```
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

And here:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I comment on this part **"return $this->user = $this->provider->retrieveById($payload['sub']);"** and waiting for a better solution